# XAML specify valid breakpoints for word wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textblock which holds a filepath to a network folder like
`\\folder\anotherfolder...`

This textblock has TextWrapping enabled and it works fine, however it breaks the path at the `\\` like the following:

```
\
\folder\anotherfolder...
```

So it looks like it has determined that the most logical breakpoint for this string is between two slashes since there aren't any spaces.

Unfortunately, this doesn't look very nice so I'd like to find a way to force it to fill each line with as many characters as possible before wrapping.  **Is there a way to specify valid breakpoints within a string?**

Answer (score 2):

I found your question interesting and have searched around. Looks like we can control the break point using some special Unicode character. One of those is helpful in your case is called ***Zero-width non-breaking space***. This has unicode of `FEFF`. By inserting that special unicode in between `//`, you can prevent that pair from being broken/separated. However the `FEFF` is deprecated since Unicode 3.2 and replaced by `2060` which is considered as ***word joiner*** character which connects the 2 sides and combines them as a word. That prevents the breaking right at the joining position.

e.g:

```
<!-- this works in earlier versions of Unicode and may still work 
     since Unicode 3.2 but it is considered as deprecated -->
<TextBlock Text="\&#xFEFF;\folder\anotherfolder..."/>
<!-- this should be used since Unicode 3.2 -->
<TextBlock Text="\&#x2060;\folder\anotherfolder..."/>
```

[Reference about those mentioned special unicodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner).

You can always use code to replace all pairs so that the special unicode is inserted in between 2 sides.